# SSRS on 2008 R2 and its Database on 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Can we have SQL Server Reporting Service on SQL Server 2008 R2 and its Database(ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB) on SQL Server 2016?

PS: Both are enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS just needs a SQL Connection to a database that supports all of the features it requires. The connection type that it uses should be forward compatible to SQL 2016 (and even 2019).

I want to ask, why not upgrade SSRS as well though?